# Connect win8 and wp8 with bluetooth

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone-8

It seems win8 can not use `PeerFinder` to connect wp8.

Is there a way to connect win8 and wp8 with bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

Is windows 8 essential, or can it be 8.1?  Windows 8.1 has a whole new Bluetooth API that 8 lacks, which you might find useful.

Comment: I tested `PeerFinder` on SurfaceRT with win8.1 but it throw exception `0x80342002`.